# Nested loop returns last 2 values

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to send multiple items to multiple contacts in my contacts list , I use nested loop but it only send the last item for each contact ignoring the rest of the items ,
I didn't know what I'm doing wrong.

here are my arrays :

```
ContactList = ['john','jem'];

itemList = [
    {
        "ItemTo": 'jhon@gmail.com',
        "ItemType": 'type1'
    },

    {
        "ItemTo": 'jem@gmail.com',
        "ItemType": 'type2'
    }
]
```

here is my JS code :

```
onClick() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.ContactList.length; i++) {
        for (let j=0; j<this.itemList; j++){
            let messageToSend = this.extractMessageDetails(
                this.ContactList[i], 
                this.itemList[j]
            );
        }
    }
} 

extractMessageDetails(contact, item) {

    const ItemTo = contact.contactId;
    const ItemType = item.type;

    const itemToSend  = {
        "ItemTo": ItemTo,
        "ItemType": ItemType
    }
    
    return itemToSend; 
}
```

Comment: `let messageToSend = this.extractMessageDetails(this.ContactList[i], this.itemList[j]);` is overwritten for each loop. Use a map plus a join instead

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: your code does nothing, you maybe create item to send in a loop but you are not doing anything with it, it si deleted when it exits loop scope, try appending results to some array or something.

Comment: Okay, so directly call your array instead of using this. , hope you get it because it is not a class so calling the array directly without a this prepending it is an improvement and the logic seems fine, but you are missing to add another array for more clarification, like where have you mentioned contact ID and where is your contact JSON ? and also take the result out, else it will only give you the last result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array messagesToSend = [] outside the second loop and then inside the 2nd loop push your object in that variable messagesToSend.push(this.extractMessageDetails(this.ContactList[i], this.itemList[j]););. So in the end of your second loop you will have messages for each contact

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.ContactList.length; i++) {
    let messagesToSend = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < this.itemList; j++) {
      messagesToSend.push( 
        this.extractMessageDetails(this.ContactList[i], this.itemList[j]););
    }
    ///send messages to contract[i]
  }
```

If you want to collect all messages for all contracts move declaration of array outside the loops

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code, since the function is called in every loop, the variable messagetosend is being overwritten every iteration hence only the last instance is being stored. Try and store them in another array instead of a single variable.